# Updating a joined-subclass in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have a base class `A` and a subclass `B`. When I retrieve an instance of `A` in a Spring form, I want to edit the instance `A` and update it as an instance of `B` in the database. A and B are both two different tables in the database, but they have been mapped using `joined-subclass`. However, when I try to convert an instance of `A` into `B` and save it as `B`, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:A
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:249)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:510)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:309)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:319)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.findDirty(TypeHelper.java:294)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4037)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:527)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:234)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:163)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:228)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:100)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:158)
at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:62)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:699)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:321)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:613)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:85
```

A and B share the same primary key value in the database.

Is there any way to convert `A` into `B` and save it as `B`. This is the code of the mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping  package="db">
    <class name="Person" table="A">
        <id name="personId" >
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="forename" length="50" not-null="true" />
        <property name="middleName" length="50" />
        <property name="surname" length="50" not-null="true" />
        <property name="birthDate"/>
        <component name="address">
            <property name="street" length="50"  />
            <property name="town" length="50"  />
            <property name="county" length="50"  />
            <property name="postcode" length="10"  />
        </component>
        <property name="telephone" length="15" />
        <property name="updateTime" not-null="true"  />
        <property name="updatedBy" not-null="true"  />
    </class>
     <joined-subclass name="db.B" extends="A">
        <key column="personId" />
        <property name="employeeDescription" />
        // more properties
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This the code for the A DAO:

```
public class HibernateADAO {
     public void updateA(A a) {
         this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(a);
     }
}
```

B DAO:

```
public class HibernateBDAO {
     public void updateB(B b) {
         this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(b);
     }
}
```

And this is the style of my controller code that I am currently using to update B:

```
 // retrieve A from db (works fine).
 A a = retrieveFromDb();
 B b = new B(a);
 // set properties of b
 if (b.getPersonId() != null) {
     A a = (A) b;
     hibernateADao.update(a);
     hibernateBDao.update(b);
 } else {
    // create new instance of B, which will also create a new A in the database.
 }
```

Comment: You can't change the type of an object. If it's an instance of A, it's an instance of A, and can't become an instance of B. If that's not what you're trying to do, then show us the code you're using, the code of the entities, and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet I have uploaded the code that I have tried. Of course, I have tried to limit as much code as possible to avoid confusion.

Comment: What does `new B(a)` do? If it copies everything, including the ID, to the new B, then it doesn't make sense: you can't have two different A instances with the same ID. If it doesn't copy the ID, then you shouldn't update B, but create it. You would then have a copy of A, but of type B.

Comment: new B(a) copied all of the attribute values of a into a new object of type B. Also, A and B are two different tables in the database. But both of them use the same personId as a PK. Only difference is that A uses an auto-increment PK, but B does not use an auto-increment.

Comment: So you want to A instances with the same ID. That obviously can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. First of all, I had to insert `B` into the database using Hibernate's `createSQLQuery()` feature to create an instance of `B` in the database using the Primary Key value from `A` (`A` was already in the database with an assigned PK value).

Once that is done, I then retrieved that saved instance of `B` from the database using Hibernate `get()`. I then set the values of more properties of that returned instance of `B`. When I updated the instance of `B`, I used `saveOrUpdate()` instead of `merge()`. Now I have a converted instance of `B` even though it was previously an instance of type `A` in the database.

It's an ugly hack, but it worked.